# Map and reduce task counts are not correct in log file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was running one mapreduce job which runs correctly. But i have certain confusion regarding the log files being generated .

Command to run the map-red

```
hadoop jar mapred-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar tcs.hadoop.org.mapreduce.MaxTemperatureDriver /priya/sample.txt /output

14/02/20 17:35:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/02/20 17:35:10 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/02/20 17:35:10 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/02/20 17:35:10 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/02/20 17:35:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201402111203_0034
14/02/20 17:35:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/20 17:35:22 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/02/20 17:35:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/02/20 17:35:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201402111203_0034
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 26
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=2
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=11900
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=23142
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=34
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=633
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=154973
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=17
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=5
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=34
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=4
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=45
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=4420
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=172822528
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=5
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=103
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=2
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=2
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=300945408
14/02/20 14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=7375564800
14/02/20 17:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=517:35:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2
```

So from this i can see i am creating one map task and two reduce task.

But while i am looking into the job history log which resides in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/history directory i am getting 5 tasks has been triggered by job tracker as below (only providing the lines of logs). **I am not able to understant why 5 tasks instead of 3.**

```
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201402111203_0034_m_000002" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000002_0" START_TIME="1392897911096" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_IMBDBOX1:IMBDBOX
1/157\.227\.44\.207:40925" HTTP_PORT="50060" .

MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="MAP" TASKID="task_201402111203_0034_m_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000000_0" TASK_STATUS="SUCCESS" FINISH_TIME="1392897989806" HOSTNAME="/defaul

ReduceAttempt TASK_TYPE="REDUCE" TASKID="task_201402111203_0034_r_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201402111203_0034_r_000001_0" START_TIME="1392897947754" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_IMBDBOX3:loc
alhost/127\.0\.0\.1:34625" HTTP_PORT="50060" 

ReduceAttempt TASK_TYPE="REDUCE" TASKID="task_201402111203_0034_r_000000" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201402111203_0034_r_000000_0" START_TIME="1392897992388" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_IMBDBOX4:loc
alhost/127\.0\.0\.1:59439" HTTP_PORT="50060" .

MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201402111203_0034_m_000001" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000001_0" START_TIME="1392898004324" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_IMBDBOX4:local
host/127\.0\.0\.1:59439" HTTP_PORT="50060"
```

Again while i am going into userlog which resides in $HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs, i can see only for one map task  the log has been generated. **Why for other  map and reduce tasks logs were not generated ?**

Please help . Thanks!

### userlog directory

```
total 8
-rw-r----- 1 hadoop hdusers 497 2014-02-20 17:35 job-acls.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hadoop hdusers  96 2014-02-20 17:35 attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000002_0 -> /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201402111203_0034/attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000002_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to this strings:

```
TASK_TYPE="SETUP"
TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP"
```

Hadoop needs several accessory jobs to run during [Map](http://wikidoop.com/wiki/Hadoop/MapReduce/Mapper)[Reduce](http://wikidoop.com/wiki/Hadoop/MapReduce/Reducer) job life cycle.

Comment: Thanks Rodi !! I had and other doubt that , in userlog , only for task attempt_201402111203_0034_m_000002_0 , which is a setup task for job has been logged. Is not it like i should also get the log for my map and reduce tasks ? I have given my userlog directory content too.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the job logs on Name Node? Did you check your Data Nodes? Hadoop stores logs locally to the job. Your maps and reduces run on Data Nodes, that's where you should look for them.